# Where can I find the system icons for Mail?

Tags: mail.app, macos

I'm trying to track down the .icns files for these icons:
[image]

Any ideas? Not seeing them in the app resource folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously in macOS Sierra, Apple has changed how it packages some of the application resources and in this particular case the image assets that comprise the toolbar are still in *Mail.app/Contents/Resources/*, at least some of them, in the *assets.car* file as shown in the image farther below. Note that there are several *.car* files in the *Resources* folder, however looking at the open files for Mail.app in Activity Monitor, there are *.car* archives outside of the application bundle that are open as well, e.g.:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/VibrantLightAppearance.car
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/SystemAppearance.car
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Assets.car
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/FunctionRowAppearance.car
```

- Note: Check in Activity Monitor on your system for a complete list of open files for Mail.app.

Doing a few Google searches, I found a few different apps, both GUI and CL, and had mixed results in both viewing and extracting assets from the *.car* archives. However, that was using only precompiled programs, and there are a few Xcode Projects I didn't test.

The one in the image below is [ThemeEngine](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine/releases) and while is actually showed more *objects* then [Asset Catalog Tinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer) did, and opened some *.car* files that Asset Catalog Tinkerer couldn't, the drawback is ThemeEngine doesn't have an export function like Asset Catalog Tinkerer did. However, I could still copy and paste out of ThemeEngine though. Maybe the Xcode Projects would work better if I compiled then on my system, but just don't have the time to try.

[image: ThemeEngine showing Mail.app Assets.car file.]

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Applications folder, right click on the Mail icon, click on the "Show Package Contents ", double click the "Contents" folder, double click the "Resources" folder. The tool bar icons should be in that folder (mine are, in Snow Leopard)

Comment: The sidebar icons are there... is there a sub directory with button icons? I'm not seeing them.

Comment: @AaronBenjamin The icons have been there up to El Capitan's Mail - in Sierra they aren't!

Comment: Any idea where they've run off to?